# Merging K Sorted Linked Lists

Tags: java, algorithm, linked-list

Specifically, how can I improve the time complexity of my algorithm (currently it is `O(listLength * numberOfLists)`)? It only beats 5% of accepted LeetCode solutions, which surprised me.

```
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * public class ListNode {
 *     int val;
 *     ListNode next;
 *     ListNode(int x) { val = x; }
 * }
 */
class Solution {
    private void advance(final ListNode[] listNodes, final int index) {
        listNodes[index] = listNodes[index].next;
    }

    public ListNode mergeKLists(final ListNode[] listNodes) {
        ListNode sortedListHead = null;
        ListNode sortedListNode = null;

        int associatedIndex;

        do {            
            int minValue = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            associatedIndex = -1;

            for (int listIndex = 0; listIndex < listNodes.length; listIndex++) {
                final ListNode listNode = listNodes[listIndex];

                if (listNode != null && listNode.val < minValue) {                
                    minValue = listNode.val;
                    associatedIndex = listIndex;
                }
            }

            // An associated index of -1 indicates no more values left in any of the given lists
            if (associatedIndex != -1) {
                if (sortedListNode == null) {
                    sortedListNode = new ListNode(minValue);
                    sortedListHead = sortedListNode;
                }
                else {
                    sortedListNode.next = new ListNode(minValue);
                    sortedListNode = sortedListNode.next;
                }

                advance(listNodes, associatedIndex);
            }
        }
        while (associatedIndex != -1);

        return sortedListHead;
    }
}
```

Note that the `Solution` class in addition to `ListNode` is already provided, the only code that I wrote was inside `mergeKLists`.

Comment: You correctly determined the complexity of your approach. No surprise that it fares low. Strive for `O(listLength * log(numberOfLists))`.

Answer (score 1):

The time complexity is \$O(\text{listLength} * \text{numberOfLists}^2)\$ because the check of *which node is the smallest?* is looking at one element of each list every iteration (so each iteration's complexity is \$O(\text{numberOfLists})\$, and there are \$\text{listLength} * \text{numberOfLists}\$ iterations.

You can get to \$O(\text{listLength} * \text{numberOfLists} * \log(\text{numberOfLists}))\$ by using a sorted list of the ListNode elements that you are checking in each iteration, instead of the unsorted array `listNodes`. Let's call this list `sortedNodes`. You can avoid checking each element of `sortedNodes` every iteration because you know the first one is the smallest, and once you take this first value into the merged list and advance the node - do a binary search to decide where to move the first element after its value has changed. (Or remove it if it got to a `null`.)

Answer (score 0):

A [comment](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/208315/merging-k-sorted-linked-lists#comment402359_208315) suggests that you can get \$\mathcal{O}(n\log{m})\$, where \$n\$ is the total number of elements in all lists and \$m\$ is the number of lists.  How would you get \$\mathcal{O}(n\log{m})\$?  The answer is to maintain a container of sorted lists.  Two possible containers are a `SortedSet` (e.g. `TreeSet`) or a `PriorityQueue` (implemented with a heap).  Both have \$\mathcal{O}(\log{m})\$ insertions and removals.  You would perform \$\mathcal{O}(n)\$ insertions and removals (i.e. one for each element of the lists).  \$\mathcal{O}(n\log{m})\$ overall.

Your current code is \$\mathcal{O}(n\cdot m)\$, so \$\mathcal{O}(n\log{m})\$ would be an improvement asymptotically.

Consider

```
    public ListNode mergeKLists(final ListNode[] listNodes) {
        PriorityQueue<ListNode> lists = new PriorityQueue<>(Arrays.asList(listNodes));

        // create a dummy head so as to have the same logic for the first node as the others
        ListNode head = new ListNode(0);
        ListNode current = head;
        for (ListNode node = lists.poll(); node != null; node = lists.poll()) {
            current.next = new ListNode(node.val);
            current = current.next;

            if (node.next != null) {
                lists.add(node.next);
            }
        }

        return head.next;
    }
```

The `for` loop will run \$n\$ times (once for each element in the lists).  The `poll` and `add` operations will each take \$\mathcal{O}(\log{m})\$ time.  So \$\mathcal{O}(n\log{m})\$ overall.  The creation of the `PriorityQueue` will take \$\mathcal{O}(m\log{m})\$, so that's \$\mathcal{O}((n + m)\log{m})\$.  If we assume that none of the lists are empty, then \$m <= n\$, so \$\mathcal{O}(n\log{m})\$.

We `return head.next` to avoid the problem of checking on each iteration if we are inserting the first element of the list.  The `head` itself is not part of the list that we are creating, just a placeholder.  Another alternative would be to create the first element outside the list.

This code assumes that none of the entries in `listNodes` are null.  If they can be, you'd need additional checking for that case.  It also assumes that `ListNode` is comparable by `val`.  If not, you'd have to pass a `Comparator` to the `PriorityQueue` constructor to implement that behavior.  The `SortedSet` version is similar, with the same limitations.

With a `Comparator` and capacity set, null checking, without a dummy head, and with `current` declared as part of the loop declaration (for better scoping, as `current` is not used outside the loop):

```
    public ListNode mergeKLists(final ListNode[] listNodes) {
        PriorityQueue<ListNode> lists = new PriorityQueue<>(listNodes.length,
                new Comparator<ListNode>() {

                    int compare(ListNode a, ListNode b) {
                        return Integer.compare(a.val, b.val);
                    }

                });

        for (ListNode node : listNodes) {
            if (node != null) {
                lists.add(node);
            }
        }

        if (lists.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }

        ListNode head = new ListNode(lists.poll().val);
        for (ListNode node = lists.poll(), current = head; node != null; node = lists.poll()) {
            current.next = new ListNode(node.val);
            current = current.next;

            if (node.next != null) {
                lists.add(node.next);
            }
        }  

        return head;
    }
```

I think that the dummy head is actually easier, but you may find this form more readable.

I haven't tested this, so beware of syntax errors, etc.